# Drools - Rule Activations for different FactHandles cancelled

Tags: drools, kie

**Rules:**

```
rule "Accounting_11" dialect "mvel" 
//For any value of l except given in Accounting_12
salience 1 
activation-group "Group l"  
auto-focus true
lock-on-active
no-loop true 
when $iv:Invoice(x in ("D20","D21","D22", "D23", "D24","D25"),y =="E20",z =="F20",a =="G20") 
then modify($iv) { sg.setA("ALL l"), sg.setB("C20")} 
end

rule "Accounting_12"  dialect "mvel" 
//Exceptions of l
salience 2  
activation-group "Group l" 
auto-focus true
lock-on-active
no-loop true 
//Pattern is similar to Accounting_11 with additional constraint "l in (....)"
when $iv:Invoice(l in ("C20","C21","C22", "C23", "C24","C25") , x in ("D20","D21","D22", "D23", "D24","D25"),y =="E20",z =="F20",a =="G20") 
then modify($iv) { sg.setA("Sepcific l"), sg.setB("C20")} 
end
```

**Inserted 2 facts in working memory in loop.**

- Invoice(l="C20", x="D20", y= "E20", z="F20",", a="G20")
- Invoice(x="D20", y= "E20", z="F20", a="G20")

**Call fireAllRules().3 activations are created, as expected.**

```
==>[ActivationCreatedEvent: getActivation()=[[ Accounting_11 active=false ] [ [fact 0:2:4445234:4445234:2:DEFAULT:NON_TRAIT:org.cpg.poc.drools.keloy.domain.Invoice@43d432] ] ], getKnowledgeRuntime()=org.drools.core.impl.StatefulKnowledgeSessionImpl@1743ccd]
    ==>[ActivationCreatedEvent: getActivation()=[[ Accounting_11 active=false ] [ [fact 0:1:2489285:2489285:1:DEFAULT:NON_TRAIT:org.cpg.poc.drools.keloy.domain.Invoice@25fbc5] ] ], getKnowledgeRuntime()=org.drools.core.impl.StatefulKnowledgeSessionImpl@1743ccd]
    ==>[ActivationCreatedEvent: getActivation()=[[ Accounting_12 active=false ] [ [fact 0:2:4445234:4445234:2:DEFAULT:NON_TRAIT:org.cpg.poc.drools.keloy.domain.Invoice@43d432] ] ], getKnowledgeRuntime()=org.drools.core.impl.StatefulKnowledgeSessionImpl@1743ccd]
```

**One of the expected activation gets fired**

```
==>[BeforeActivationFiredEvent:  getActivation()=[[ Accounting_12 active=false ] [ [fact 0:2:4445234:4445234:2:DEFAULT:NON_TRAIT:org.cpg.poc.drools.keloy.domain.Invoice@43d432] ] ], getKnowledgeRuntime()=org.drools.core.impl.StatefulKnowledgeSessionImpl@1743ccd]
```

**But it cancels out ALL the other activations.**

```
==>[ActivationCancelledEvent: getCause()=CLEAR, getActivation()=[[ Accounting_11 active=false ] [ [fact 0:2:4445234:4445234:2:DEFAULT:NON_TRAIT:org.cpg.poc.drools.keloy.domain.Invoice@43d432] ] ], getKnowledgeRuntime()=org.drools.core.impl.StatefulKnowledgeSessionImpl@1743ccd]
==>[ActivationCancelledEvent: getCause()=CLEAR, getActivation()=[[ Accounting_11 active=false ] [ [fact 0:1:2489285:2489285:1:DEFAULT:NON_TRAIT:org.cpg.poc.drools.keloy.domain.Invoice@25fbc5] ] ], getKnowledgeRuntime()=org.drools.core.impl.StatefulKnowledgeSessionImpl@1743ccd]
```

**Should it NOT cancel only the activation created for same fact-handle (Invoice@43d432) , the one with l=C20 ?**

Why it cancels the activation created for **Invoice@25fbc5** , the second one with null value for 'l'?

*Note:* When I fire the rules after each fact insertion, I get the expected result.

Comment: Absolutely: the way the rules are written in combination with the fact data and the consequence code are bound to cause the effects you have described.

Comment: Seeing the rules and knowing the data will tell you why...

Comment: @luane, should it not cancel the other activations only for the respective fact ?

Comment: We can play this game for hours and days. You report that something happens and ask why, and I'll tell you that **you alone** have all the information to explain it. Huh.

Comment: @luane. Sorry for the incomplete question.I am working on the activation-group and lock-on-active. All the rules belong to same activation-group with lock-on-active to true. I will try to post the rules.

Comment: By all means - it really might help. But lock-on-active is very likely to create just the effect you've described. - Explaining what you want to achieve might be the best way to resolve your problem.

Comment: @luane. I have given the rules.It was in xls. Couldn't post the image.Had to convert it to drl. Why the activation created for the second fact/object is also cancelled ? Should it not cancel the activation for the first fact/object only ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79539/discussion-between-ahamedmustafam-and-laune).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using rule attributes no-loop and lock-on-active is advertised as simplifying rule authoring, which is true in a certain percentage of use cases. It is, however, *always* a way to avoid stringent application of *logic*, the fundament of rule conditions. Although adding full logic to rule conditions may require more work, it'll most certainly create a logic that is robust, resulting in the rule executions you really desire.

That said, I don't see what should happen due to the inserted rules. Clearly, the constraints of Accounting_11 and Accounting_12 are overlapping, Accounting_12 being more restrictive. This is always a dubious situation: do you want both consequences to happen or just one? Accounting_12 has the higher alience, so it'll be preferred (irrespective of the value of field `l`). Without rule attributes I'd expect the other activation to remain active, but with `lock-on-active`, activations are cancelled.

As I said: describing the required logic in elementary constraints is preferable.

If, for instance, rule should not be activated for `l` values being in the range defined by the set `("C20", "C21", "C22", "C23", "C24", "C25"), add this constraint:

```
$iv:Invoice(l not in ("C20", "C21", "C22", "C23", "C24", "C25"),...)
```

Comment: I want Invoice-1 to be modified by Accounting_12. And Invoice-2 to be modified by Accounting_11

Comment: Ah! This clarifies the issue. See my answer, edited now.